# What can I do to ensure one of my pins aren't triggered if another pin is triggered?

Tags: logic-gates

I'm building a "Rock, Paper, Scissors" game. The problem I'm having is when Player A selects "Rock", and Player B selects both "Paper" and "Scissors", my pin "Player B Wins" is triggered, as well as my pin "Invalid input, selected only one option".

The "Player B Wins" is triggered due to the fact that Player B selects "Paper", and Player A selects "Rock" and Rock beats Paper. What can I do, however, to make sure that Player B will not win if they select multiple options? Here is my diagram so far (It's very messy, as I am very new to logisim, gate diagrams, etc):
[image]

Comment: How about OR-ing all of your 'Invalid' signals together and using that result to inhibit both of the 'Win' signals?

Comment: Google 'quiz game' circuits that lock out any other answer so each player can only select only ONE of their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [Priority Encoder](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc148.pdf) to encode the player choices. If a player selects "Rock" then the other choices are ignored. If player doesn't select "Rock" but selects "Paper" then they get "Paper" regardless of whether "Scissors" is selected. They only get "Scissors" if they did not choose "Paper" or "Rock".

Truth table for encoding one player's choices looks like this:

```
Rock    Paper   scissors    encoded as
0       0       0           00 (nothing)
1       x       x           01 (rock)
0       1       x           10 (paper)
0       0       1           11 (scissors)
```

or fully expanded to show all eight rows:

```
Rock    Paper   scissors    encoded as
0       0       0           00 (nothing)
1       0       0           01 (rock)
1       0       1           01 (rock)
1       1       0           01 (rock)
1       1       1           01 (rock)
0       1       0           10 (paper)
0       1       1           10 (paper)
0       0       1           11 (scissors)
```

Then (spoilers!) the game logic would compare these two 2-bit encoded choices to choose the winner:

```
Player A        Player B        Outcome
00 (nothing)    xx              (pending)
xx              00 (nothing)    (pending)
01 (rock)       01 (rock)       (tie)
01 (rock)       10 (paper)      (B wins: paper covers rock)
01 (rock)       11 (scissors)   (A wins: rock breaks scissors)
10 (paper)      01 (rock)       (A wins: paper covers rock)
10 (paper)      10 (paper)      (tie)
10 (paper)      11 (scissors)   (B wins: scissors cuts paper)
11 (scissors)   01 (rock)       (B wins: rock breaks scissors)
11 (scissors)   10 (paper)      (A wins: scissors cuts paper)
11 (scissors)   11 (scissors)   (tie)
```

again, X = don't care 0 or 1, so XX is an abbreviation for four rows of the truth table = 00, 01, 10, or 11.

> Further exercise, left for the student: extend this design to play `Rock-Paper-Scissors-Spock-Lizard`.

I like this question, I may start using this as a job interview question...